# SQLTransaction in .NET

Tags: commit, sqltransaction

I begin transaction as here

```
this.cmd.Transaction = (await this.cmd.Connection.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.Snapshot)) as SqlTransaction;
```

Then i tried to Commit transaction using

```
cmd.CommandText = "COMMIT TRAN";
await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

The program throws an exeption "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0"
What is the problem, and why i can't commit transaction such this?

With

```
cmd.Transaction.CommitAsync()
```

it works.

Comment: Exactly which `SqlClient` library are you using? And what version of .NET?